# The command could not be located

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, environment-variables, path

I found this whenever I open a terminal window.
Can someone find a permanent solution of this?

```
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1: Is a directory
Command 'dircolors' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dircolors
 * /usr/bin/dircolors

The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
Command 'dirname' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dirname
 * /usr/bin/dirname

The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dirname: command not found
Command 'dirname' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dirname
 * /usr/bin/dirname

The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dirname: command not found
```

I am using this below command for temporary purpose:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Just fix your shell's initialization file. If you don't know how to do that, consider showing it to us in your question (not in comments). I'm guessing you have issues with your `PATH` variable (since the standard paths `/bin` and `/usr/bin` is not included) and with your setup of the Java-related environment (since you're trying to execute a directory; although this may be an issue related to a faulty `PATH` variable).

Comment: Can you let me know how to fix it up?

Comment: You have some statement in your shell's startup files, possibly `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, which resets the `PATH` variable, deleting its previous value. You need to fix this.  If you don't know what you're looking for in these file, consider adding them to the question.

Comment: Removing /bin and /usr/bin from your path is not typically useful.  What is your purpose for doing this?  Perhaps there is a better solution.  Or maybe you didn't intend to remove them and you were trying to do something else?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to fix this:

- Put /bin and /usr/bin back into your path so that commands in your shell init files can function correctly
- Edit your shell init files to remove commands that are not in your path or skip running them if the required path components are missing

The shell init files are hidden files in your home directory.  The names of these files depends on what shell you are using.   For example, if you are using bash, the files would include .bashrc .bash_profile and .profile

However, editing these files could cause your account to not function correctly if you add errors to them.  It would be best to just make sure your path is correct, or if you really need to temporarily remove /bin or /usr/bin from your path, ignore the errors this causes.

Comment: I don't want any kind of messages to be shown when I open the terminal window. Currently facing the similar problem. As I mentioned in query:
I am using this below command for temporary purpose:
'''
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
'''
which is working fine for me. But I am looking for permanent solution.

Comment: I have already listed two possible permanent solutions.  The best way to remove error messages like this is to correct configuration problems in your account configuration.